# commands like 'stack exec — yesod --help'

Tags: yesod

In the Yesod book
https://www.yesodweb.com/book/scaffolding-and-the-site-template
commands are given like
'stack exec — yesod --help'
and
'stack exec — yesod devel'
but what is that '—' symbol (I can only copy / paste it), and what is its meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called an em dash [(and how to create it on your keyboard)](http://www.techtoolsforwriters.com/how-to-create-an-em-dash/). In the case where it is being used with Yesod, it is somewhat unclear to me if using the em dash was on purpose or not. Some programs (like Microsoft Word) automatically convert two hyphens (`--`) into an em dash. I think this may be what happened in this case - because over at GitHub there [is a post](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/1018) where the command `stack exec -- yesod devel` is used. This would be more consistent with typical command line usage of hyphens - [the single and double hyphens are supposed to have specific/standard meaning when used in command line utilities](https://serverfault.com/questions/387935/whats-the-difference-betwen-the-single-dash-and-double-dash-flags-on-shell-comm).

Comment: Based on you answer I experimented somewhat further and found that the em dash has to be replaced with -- followed by a space (as you said). The space thereafter is crucial, and is what I initialy left out.
So the given commands are:
'stack exec -- yesod --help'
and
'stack exec -- yesod devel'.
Thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome! If you think my answer suitable answered your question you may accept it by clicking the check mark

Comment: OK I clicked the check mark (I'm not only new with Haskell / Yesod but also with StackOverflow).
I noticed the em dashes in the online book are changed now to double hyphens!